# node-rdkafka: seek to end and get position

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm trying to build a consumer that blocks some actions until it read all current messages from start to end.

I can't find any methods for finding out number of messages on a topic. My current idea is to seek to `latest` check position and then seek back to `earliest`.

My current implementation looks like.

```
class KafkaReader {
...
private _connectConsumer() {
        this._logger.debug('Starting consumer with ', this._config.brokerList, this._config.groupId);
        const conf = {
            'metadata.broker.list': this._config.brokerList,
            'group.id': this._config.groupId,
        };

        if (this._config.debug) {
            conf['debug'] = this._config.debug;
        }

        this._consumer = new KafkaConsumer(conf, {
            'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest' // consume from the start
        });


        this._consumer.on('data', (message: ConsumerStreamMessage) => {
            if (this._config.debug) {
                this._logger.debug('Received message', message.topic, message.value.toString('utf8'));
            }

            this._subject.next(message.value.toString('utf8'));
        });

        this._consumer.on('ready', (arg) => { this._onConsumerReady(arg); });

        this._consumer.connect();
    }

    private _onConsumerReady(arg: any) {
        this._logger.debug('Kafka consumer ready.' + JSON.stringify(arg));

        this._consumer.subscribe([this._topic.topicId]);

        this._logger.debug('before seek end', this._consumer.position(null));
        this._consumer.seek({'topic': this._topic.topicId, 'offset': 'latest', 'partition': 0}, 0, (b) => {
            const end = this._consumer.position(null);
            this._logger.debug('end', end, b);
            this._seekToEarliestAndConsume();
        });
    }

    private _seekToEarliestAndConsume() {
        this._consumer.seek({'topic': this._topic.topicId, 'offset': 'earliest', 'partition': 0}, 0, () => {
            this._consumer.consume();
            this._startUpSequence.next(true);
            this._startUpSequence.complete();
        });
    }
}
```

I get the output:

```
[2019-08-01T13:13:15.156] [DEBUG] kafka-reader - before seek end []
[2019-08-01T13:13:15.157] [DEBUG] kafka-reader - end [] { Error: Local: Erroneous state
    at Function.createLibrdkafkaError [as create] (node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/error.js:334:10)
    at node_modules/node-rdkafka/lib/kafka-consumer.js:229:26
  message: 'Local: Erroneous state',
  code: -172,
  errno: -172,
  origin: 'kafka' }
```

It looks like the second seek works as expected but the first one gives me `Local: Erroneous state`.

- Does anyone know how to get the position of the last message?
- Why does it throw `Local: Erroneous state` when trying to seek to latest?

Seek requires that the partition is specified, is there away around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know much about node.js implementation, but standard Consumer API has both `public Map<TopicPartition, Long> beginningOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions, Duration timeout)` and `public Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)` methods that do not require changing consumer position. See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L2070

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get this error, but shouldn't you use instead :

```
queryWatermarkOffsets(topic, partition, timeout, cb)
Query offsets from the broker. This function makes a call to the broker to get the current low (oldest/beginning) and high (newest/end) offsets for a topic partition.
```

From here :
https://blizzard.github.io/node-rdkafka/current/KafkaConsumer.html

Yannick

Answer (score 0):

You need to have message on all the partitions in order to seek otherwise you will get this error. I went through same error and later removed the partitions from seeking for which there were no messages and it solved that error. Not sure, if it helps but thought of putting it here.